# Nextjs higher order API function: resolver is not a function

Tags: typescript, next.js, higher-order-functions

I want to write a wrapper for my NextJs API routes that checks for a JWT in the request, validates it and then executes the original API handler.

So I've defined my wrapper function like so

```
interface ApiError {
  message: string,
}

export async function withJwt<T>(
  handler: ((req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<T>, user?: User)=>void|Promise<void>))
  : Promise<(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<T | ApiError>)=>Promise<void>> {  
  return async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<T | ApiError>) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if(!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith(JWT_PREFIX)){ 
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: `Provide the header 'Authorization: ${JWT_PREFIX}<token>'`,
      });
    }
    let user: User;
    try {
      user = await verify(authHeader.substring(JWT_PREFIX.length));
    } catch(err) {
      return res.status(401).json({message: (err as any).message as string});
    }

    try {
      return handler(req, res, user);
    } catch(err){
      return res.status(500).json({message: (err as any).message});
    }
  };
}
```

Then, my API route looks like this

```
// page/api/hello.ts

type Data = {
  name: string
}

const wrapped = withJwt((
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) => {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
});

export default wrapped;
```

Yet, when I navigate to `/api/hello`, I get the following error output:

> Server Error
>
> TypeError: resolver is not a function
>
> Uncaught     at Object.apiResolver
> (file:///root/projects/taskmanager-next/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils.js:101:15)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async DevServer.runApi (file:///root/projects/taskmanager-next/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:320:9)
> at async Object.fn (file:///root/projects/taskmanager-next/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:486:37)
> at async Router.execute (file:///root/projects/taskmanager-next/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:228:32)
> at async DevServer.run (file:///root/projects/taskmanager-next/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:598:29)
> at async DevServer.run (file:///root/projects/taskmanager-next/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:444:20)
> at async DevServer.handleRequest (file:///root/projects/taskmanager-next/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:305:20)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out:

My mistake was to make `withJwt` an `async` function. Only the returned function needs to be `async` and therefore return a Promise.

So the following is working:

```
export function withJwt<T>(
  handler: ((req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<T>, user?: User)=>void|Promise<void>))
  : (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<T | ApiError>)=>Promise<void> {  
  return async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<T | ApiError>) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if(!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith(JWT_PREFIX)){ 
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: `Provide the header 'Authorization: ${JWT_PREFIX}<token>'`,
      });
    }
    let user: User;
    try {
      user = await verify(authHeader.substring(JWT_PREFIX.length));
    } catch(err) {
      return res.status(401).json({message: (err as any).message as string});
    }

    try {
      return handler(req, res, user);
    } catch(err){
      return res.status(500).json({message: (err as any).message});
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Note: `async` function always returns a promise; so calling `withJwt(...)` assigned a promise to `wrapped`, not the inner function returned by `withJwt`.